# remove all line breaks (enter symbols) from the string using R

Tags: r, regex, line-breaks

How to remove all line breaks (enter symbols) from the string?

```
my_string <- "foo\nbar\rbaz\r\nquux"
```

I've tried `gsub("\n", "", my_string)`, but it doesn't work, because new line and line break aren't equal.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You need to strip `\r` and `\n` to remove carriage returns and new lines.

```
x <- "foo\nbar\rbaz\r\nquux"
gsub("[\r\n]", "", x)
## [1] "foobarbazquux"
```

Or

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(x, "[\r\n]" , "")
## [1] "foobarbazquux"
```

Comment: Will this work if its a literal "\n" in the string?

Comment: @Mojimi - I've just come across this problem, and find that using `gsub("[\\n]",...)` works.

Comment: @ThomasRushton, that found all instances of the letter n for me.

Answer (score 22):

I just wanted to note here that if you want to insert spaces where you found newlines the best option is to use the following:

```
gsub("\r?\n|\r", " ", x)
```

which will insert only one space regardless whether the text contains `\r\n`, `\n` or `\r`.

Comment: This is a nice and complete answer.  I like the `\r\n` touch.  Note that one can use `trimws(x, "right")` to quickly trim off newline and carriage returns if they appear only at the end of `x`.  This will, of course, trim trailing spaces, tabs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have had success with:

```
gsub("\\\n", "", x)
```

Answer (score 0):

With `stringr::str_remove_all`

```
library(stringr)
str_remove_all(my_string, "[\r\n]")
# [1] "foobarbazquux"
```